# Android MediaPlayer prepare failed: status = 0x1 and Mediaplayer.creat() returns null with .AAC audio file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, aac

I am accessing the audio files from

> /data/user/0/app_packagename/files/filename

I don't have `WRITE_EXTERNAL` `READ_EXTERNAL` permissions.

Now I can access files which are saved in the `/data/user/0/app_packagename/files/` without `WRITE_EXTERNAL` `READ_EXTERNAL` permissions.

And can able to play all the audio files in my application.

In my application I am playing all files in queue. Few of my users are not able to play second audio file once 1st audio file completed.

Below is my code

```
void playNext(File varientFile) {
    if (mSessionMediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mSessionMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mSessionMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mSessionMediaPlayer.release();
        mSessionMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mSessionMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    if (mSessionMediaPlayer != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(variantFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
     mSessionMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mSessionMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);      
        mSessionMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mSessionMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mSessionMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                       playNext(mFiles.get(mNextIndex);
            }
        });
        mSessionMediaPlayer.start();
        runScheduler();
    }
}
```

Instead of

> mSessionMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

I had tried with

> mSessionMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
>   uri);

Even `MediaPlayer.create()` is returning `null`. `mSessionMediaPlayer.prepare()` is throwing an exception

> Cause : Prepare failed.: status=0x1

Whats wrong with my code? Why it is getting `null` or `prepare failed`? I had tested the files as well they are working, audio file format is in `.aac`.

The same user who is not able to play second audio file. He is able to play first file with the same code. But if same method is calling from onCompleted() it is not working. Why so?

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new object every time, try with the same Media Player object something like this.

```
MediaPlayer mSessionMediaPlayer;
mSessionMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
mSessionMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mSessionMediaPlayer) {
       moveToNext(mSessionMediaPlayer,nextUri);
    }

});
mSessionMediaPlayer.prepare();
mSessionMediaPlayer.start();



private void moveToNext(MediaPlayer mSessionMediaPlayer,Uri uri){
     mSessionMediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
     mSessionMediaPlayer.prepare();
     mSessionMediaPlayer.start();
}
```